# remove_action fails on woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, hook, woocommerce

I wrote a simple plugin that performs some logic on thumbnails in WooCommerce. This plugin worked great for about a year, until the client switched to a new theme. Now the plugin is no longer working and I've narrowed the problem to `remove_action()` failing.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
if (! remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10) ) {
    echo 'FAILED to remove action<br/>';
}

/**
 * WooCommerce Loop Product Thumbs
 **/

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is because of the order plugins are loaded, or if I'm making the call incorrectly due to a change in WooCommerce. I've read some topics that indicate the `remove_action()` should follow my custom `add_action()` so I reversed the order accordingly. It doesn't work either way - `remove_action()` is always returning FALSE.

I've been banging my head against a wall all day trying to figure this out. Can anyone give me a clue on a sure-fire way to execute the remove, or a way to debug it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the priority flag of [add/remove]_action() to something higher, like 90.

It's a little hard to guess without seeing what the theme is actually doing!

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 90);
if (! remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 90) ) {
    echo 'FAILED to remove action<br/>';
}
```